# ForceBindIP on right click menu problems

Tags: windows, networking

I'm trying to add [ForceBindIP](http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) to my right click context menu and here's what I have attempted thus far.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\ForceBindIP]
@="Run through wireless network"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\ForceBindIP\command]
@="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP -i {952FD65F-A2F8-4C5A-94E1-14259C576110} \"%l\""
```

Now, when I right click "Firefox" and "Run on wireless network" I reveive the "open with" dialog asking me to find an application I would like to open "firefox.exe" with.

Does anyone know why it would ask to do this?

The numbers between the `{}` are the `GUID` for the network interface.

I have no idea what `\"%1\"` is supposed to do but these are found within other options of the right click menu registry keys, so I assume they are a calling card for the application you have right clicked and the quotes in that should be to resolve white space in program directories. (please correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have save the ForceBindIP.exe in C:\Windows\Syswow64 folder.

\"%1\" is the path that the application you run. I didn't get this work on my Windows 7 64-Bits machine. I have to change it to "%1" %* to get it work.

Hope it helps.